# A conjecture on bounded complex partial sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, conjectures, geometric-series

A friend of mine has made the following conjecture, but we don't know how to prove it.

Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb {N}}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers. 
Suppose that for every complex $z\neq 1 $ with $|z|=1$, there exists a constant $C_z>0 $ verifying
$$\forall N\geq 0, \qquad \left|\sum_{i=0}^N z^{a_i}\right|  <C_z$$
Then the sequence $(a_n) $ contains all but finitely many natural numbers.

For exemple, if $a_n=2n$, the property is not verified with $z=-1$.

Can you find a proof or a counterexample?

Comment: Try $a_n = 3n$.

Comment: Well, this is not a counterexample (try $z=e^{2i\pi /3} $).

Comment: Ah, I see you are right. Hmm.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the conjecture was not true :)

Answer (score -1):

I have failed to prove this conjecture and am currently trying to find a counterexample.
Any linear transformations (eg $$a_n = k*n + r$$)  won't work as a counterexample since unit roots will be a problem so I've tried looking at sequences like $$a_n = n^2$$ 
I have not proven that the series converges (it doesn't seem easy since usual tests won't work) but according to wolfram alpha it does converge even if |z| = 1. Which would mean that the conjecture is false.

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+z%5E%28n%5E2%29+from+0+to+infinity

I don't really know what the strange looking function is though (when I look at the latex code it's written "curly theta") and it might be above my level to show that the series converge if |z| =1.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work for $z=e^{2\pi i /3} $ since $n^2\equiv 0, 1\pmod 3 $.

Comment: Hmmm why would it make it not work though? I have a hard time seeing it :/

Comment: A drawing shows it directly ;)